# How can I use macros in Perl?

Tags: perl

How do I use macros in Perl, like I do in C?

Example:

```
#define value 100 
print value;
```

I want to get the output as 100.

Comment: Why do you want to use macros in Perl? There are probably many other much better features that a high level language has to offer for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes: This is an example where you do **not** need macros: "use constant value => 100; print value;" is perfectly fine.  Acase where you would actually need a macro would be some assert()-like construct like `print "$condition failed!\n" if (!$condition);`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you just want to define constants (like your example) rather than full macros, there are a couple of perl ways to do this.

Some people like:

```
use constant value => 100;
print value;
```

Note that 'value' is a subroutine, not a 'variable'. This means you cannot interpolate it in strings so you have to do. `print "The value is ".value."\n";`.

The "[Best Practices](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&lpg=PT189&ots=Hk3jkOyAlt&dq=perl%20best%20practices%20constant&pg=PT77#v=onepage&q=&f=false)" crowd like:

```
use Readonly;
Readonly my $value => 100;
print $value;
```

However, unlike constant, Readonly is not part of the core perl distribution and so needs to be installed from CPAN.

Comment: Constants are difficult to interpolate into a string, amongst other problems. Use **Readonly**.

Comment: Duncan: constants get optimized away if(someconst){...} will go away entirely during compilation if someconst is false. That is NOT the case for Readonly variables. Also, if you insist on using Readonly, ALWAYS install Readonly::XS!

Comment: @tsee, sounds like micro-optimisation. I'm sure `if(0)` is fast enough; aside from that, the OP isn't asking for `#ifdef`. See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly#COMPARISON_WITH_"use_constant" - use constant has tons of problems.

Comment: @rjh: I disagree on most of the criticism in the Readonly documentation. Furthermore, the compile-time behaviour means that you also save the memory of the OP-structure of the code. Regarding if(0): You're wrong: With Readonly (at least the pure-perl version), you actually pay at least one subroutine call per access. That's *a lot* since subroutine calls are very slow. If you consider something like ''Readonly my $DEBUG'', and use it for debugging output liberally, you pay dearly at run-time.

Comment: Constants aren't _that_ difficult to interpolate into strings. Thy might be slightly annoying, but not difficult.

Comment: @tsee: I agree with your point about Readonly - XS is a given. Still, as a Moose user, I'm quite used to trading performance for more maintainable and less error-prone code.

Comment: @brian - could you please elaborate? Did you mean http://dev.perl.org/perl6/rfc/252.html? perldoc constant explicitly states "Constants defined using this module cannot be interpolated into strings like variables" - and I don't recall any way interpolation would work on a subroutine. Thanks!

Comment: Don't put too much stock in Perl 6 RFCs. Every crank came out to say all sorts of dumb things. It's not that difficult to write @{[CONSTANT]}, among the 10 other ways you could do the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

Perl is not C.  You would be much better served by learning the corresponding Perl idioms (such as the already mentioned `use constant value => 100`) than by trying to drag C idioms into Perl.

Answer (score 10):

For constants, the common way is to use a constant subroutine that will get inlined by the compiler:

```
use constant value => 100;
```

or

```
sub value () {100}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

#### macro.pl

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    #define a 10;
    print a;
```

And run this code using -P switch.

Example:
`perl -P macro.pl`

And use the module [Filter::cpp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Filter::cpp) also.

Comment: From the perlrun man page: "NOTE: Use of -P is strongly discouraged because of its inherent problems, including poor portability."

Comment: Although this technically answered the question, it would be better if it mentioned how messy things get when running a whole perl script through the C pre-processor with the -P flag. Indeed the perlrun manpage says in boldface "NOTE: Use of -P is strongly discouraged because of its inherent problems, including poor portability. It is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Perl."

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Comment: @Gavin - doesn't "P" stand for "Production"? :)